# If the moon became a black hole, how much lower would the temperature be on Earth's surface?

Tags: visible-light, thermal-radiation, estimation, geophysics, moon

I [read](https://what-if.xkcd.com/129/) that if the Sun became a black hole the Earth would become colder, but the effect would be negligible because the mass of the hole is still there so there would still be tides.

But, how much would the Earth cool down due to the absence of the moonlight?

Comment: I think you are reading that article incorrectly. That article is already about what would happen if the moon became a black hole, not the sun. There are plenty of other articles that would explain to you what would happen if the sun became a black hole but this one does not.

Comment: I knew it was about the moon

Comment: What are the odds that the moon becomes a black hole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is already in the article you linked. The Earth would be 1.2 milli-degrees Fahrenheit cooler without thermal radiation from the moon.

Comment: This also explains why people like Sun but not Moon bathing.